# Reducer that groups by two values

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a case in which Mapper emits data that belongs to a subgroup and the subgroup belongs to a group.

I need to add up all the values in the subgroup and find the minimal value between all subgroups of the group, for each of the groups.

So, I have an output from Mapper that looks like this

```
Group 1

group,subgroupId,value
Group1,1,2
Group1,1,3
Group1,1,4
Group1,2,1
Group1,2,2
Group1,3,1
Group1,3,2
Group1,3,5

Group 2

group,subgroupId,value
Group2,4,2
Group2,4,3
Group2,4,4
Group2,5,1
Group2,5,2
Group2,6,1
Group2,6,2
```

And my output should be

```
Group1, 1, (2+3+4)
Group1, 2, (1+2)
Group1, 3, (1+2+5)

Group1 min = min((2+3+4),(1+2),(1+2+5))
```

Same for Group 2.

So I practically need to group twice, first group by GROUP and then inside of it group by SUBGROUPID.

So I should emit the minimal sum from a group, in the given example my reducer should emit (2,3), since the minimal sum is 3 and it comes from element with id 2.

So, it seems that it could be solved best using reduce twice, first reduce would get elements grouped by id and that would be passed to the second Reducer grouped by Group id.

Does this make sense and how to implement it? I've seen ChainedMapper and ChainedReducer, but they don't fit for this purpose.

Thanks

Comment: How do the mappers know which `id` is in which group? Can you give a sample of the original input? Or is the group not important, and you're just identifying the input splits (and you have two mappers)?

Comment: That's the thing, each of the records belongs to some group, so the information about the group exits with each record. So I have to group by a group and then by subgroup (that actually contains records with the same key). I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

If all data can fit in the memory of one machine, you can simply do all this in a single job, using a single reducer (`job.setNumReducers(1);`) and two temp variables. The output is emitted in the cleanup phase of the reducer. Here is the pseudocode for that, if you use the new Hadoop API (that supports the `cleanup()` method):

```
int tempKey;
int tempMin;    

setup() {
    tempMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}

reduce(key, values) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (values.hasNext()) {
        sum += values.next();
    }
    if (sum < tempMin) {
        tempMin = sum;
        tempKey = key;
    }
}

cleanup() { //only in the new API
    emit(tempKey, tempMin);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this does not consider the groups. Maybe I haven't expressed my problem clear enough. So I'm not trying to find minimal sum, for each of the keys, but minimal sum for each of the keys for all keys IN A GROUP. So my values need to be grouped not only by key, but firstly by group and then by key. Please reconsider my question. What would you do in that case? Also, is it a recommended way to do things like this on a single machine? I believe that it could be faster without communication between nodes in a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach (summarized below), is how I would do it.

Job 1:

1. Mapper: Assigns an `id` to a `subgroupid`
2. Combiner/Reducer(same class): Finds the minimum `value` for
   `subgroupid`.

Job 2:

1. Mapper: Assigns a `groupid` to a `subgroupid`.
2. Combiner/Reducer(same class): Finds the minimum `value` for
   `groupid`.

This is best implemented in two jobs for the following reasons:

- Simplifies the mapper and reducer significantly (you don't need to worry about finding all the `groupids` the first time around). Finding the `(groupid, subgroupid)` pairs in the mapper could be non-trivial. Writing the two mappers should be trivial.
- Follows the map reduce programming guidelines given by [Tom White in Hadoop: The Definitive Guide (Chapter 6).](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449311520)
- An Oozie workflow can easily and simply accommodate the dependent jobs.
- The intermediate file products `(key:subgroupid, value: min value for subgroupid)` should be small, limiting the use of network resources.

Comment: Actually I think an even better way could be writing a custom partitioner which partitions the map results by groupid. I will think about it and respond later.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure what you mean by this assignments. Group id is already assigned and subgroup id is actually identified by record key. Maybe I wasn't explicit enough, I have edited my question a bit. First of all, first job you presented should find sum, second should find min. The thing is, I don't need the second Mapper, it would only forward results from Reducer that calculates sum. Also, I think that Oozie is heavyweight for my problem. And there is also a question if the intermediate output is too small, should it be sent to another job at all. Please reconsider

Comment: On the other hand, the idea with partitioner seems reasonable. Maybe you could post that idea as an answer and explain your idea a bit?